# How to find the files have been removed in Shell?

Tags: shell, deleted-files

If I deleted a file, how am I able to display that file just removed?
For example: I deleted a file named A, if I run my shell, that will display file A have been removed.

Comment: you can use ``-v`` to see whats happening..thats all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for recently deleted files, one way is with the `history` command.

```
history | grep 'rm ' | grep -v grep
   54  sudo rm test.php 
  374  sudo rm ufw_rules 
  465  rm N290.zip 
  614  rm rootPy.py
```